Problem binding state for elements inside a ContentDialog
I'm currently trying to revive somebody else's project.
In the original project there's a "MainMenu" page which utilizes a ContentDialog.
I've added a single checkbox to that menu and tried binding to it via x:Bind.
The MenuViewModel looks like this
namespace NScumm.MonoGame.ViewModels
{
    public class MenuViewModel : ViewModel, IMenuViewModel
    {
        private bool _showFPS;

        public bool ShowFPS
        {
            get { return _showFPS; }
            set 
            { 
                RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _showFPS, value);
            }
        }
    }
}

There's a more generic viewmodel that implements OnPropertyChanged
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace NScumm.MonoGame.ViewModels
{
    public abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var eh = PropertyChanged;
            eh?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public virtual void RaiseAndSetIfChanged<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            {
                field = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            }
        }
    }
}

Inside the codebehind I initialize the MenuViewModel
public MainMenuPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Vm = new MenuViewModel();
        DataContext = Vm;
    }

    public MenuViewModel Vm { get; set; }

Finally, in the XAML I add the checkbox
<CheckBox x:Name="ShowFPScheckBox" Margin="5" IsChecked="{x:Bind Vm.ShowFPS, Mode=TwoWay}">FPS Counter</CheckBox>

Whenever I close and re-open the menu, the checkbox is back to its default value of false.
Am I doing something wrong or is there a known issue with ContentDialog not retaining its state?


Whenever I close and re-open the menu, the checkbox is back to its
default value of false.

 Vm = new MenuViewModel();
 DataContext = Vm;

Every time you open the ContentDialog, a new Vm is created with the default Boolean value false.
If you want ContentDialog to remember your choice, it is recommended that you use a database or local resource to save the user's selection and read it each time you open it.
private void ContentDialog_Closing(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogClosingEventArgs args)
{
    bool isChecked = ShowFPScheckBox.IsChecked ?? false;
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["FpsCheckBoxState"] = isChecked;
  
}

private void ContentDialog_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["FpsCheckBoxState"]!=null)
    {
        ShowFPScheckBox.IsChecked = (bool)ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["FpsCheckBoxState"];
    }
    else
    {
        ShowFPScheckBox.IsChecked = false;
    }

}


Thanks. I just realized I was creating a new instance and to embrace singletons. Will refactor the code accordingly.

This worked like a charm.
Curious. Is there a way to listen for those local data changes (ApplicationData.Current.DataChanged will apparently only work with roaming data) or will I still need a "global" viewmodel or some sort of messaging bus?

"Is there a way to listen for those local data changes" currently not available, as documented “ApplicationData.DataChanged Event occurs when roaming application data is synchronized.”. Your function should be some kind of setting. If you want customers to keep the same settings when logging on different devices, then you need a database service. If it is just a local setting, then "local resource" is a good choice. It is not recommended to use global variables viewmodel.

Yea. The local setting works perfectly. I'm just looking for a way to propagate the change to other components now.
Would've been great if my label inside the other view could just listen for a change to "FpsCheckBoxState" and react accordingly.
